# CSS Media Queries and Size of Images

Tags: css, media-queries

I'm currently implementing the CSS Media Queries in my WordPress blog and I'm wondering is there any known method on how could I resize a blog image with a width of 400-600px to fit in a screen resolution of an iTouch, iPhone and other smartphone which have small screens.

My idea is to add this CSS:

```
.blogpost img {
    width:55%;
    height:55%;
}
```

so that it would automatically resize **all** the images in my blog. I need help with this matter. I'm not contented with my approach since I've heard that it will distort the image. Any professional advice?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It'll distort the image if you specify both the width and the height, why not just specify one?  Then you can add a min-width to make sure it doesn't get too small.  The height will adjust with the width as long as you don't specify it.

```
.blogpost img {
width:55%;
min-width:220px;
}
```

Or you could approach it a little differently and instead make the image 100% width, then make sure it doesn't go over it's actual width (so you don't distort it).  This would work well if all of your images were the same size.

```
.blogpost img {
width:100%;
max-width:600px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice @m0ose89, i have different image sizes but not lower than 400px. I hope this works. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using CSS's `max-height` and `max-width` properties:

http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Comment: Question: If i implement the .img-container, do i need to visit all the images and add the <div class="img-container"></div>? It's a bit hard to do that especially for a photo/blog which have thousands of images.

Comment: maybe just build an include and inside that include you could have an image variable that sets width and height as well as whatever images need to populate...

Answer (score -1):

You can do it by using the css **min-width/height** property. It is really easy and straightforward thing.

Comment: This does provide an answer to one who understand.